# Grails Gorm dynamicUpdate does not change the update queries

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am using Grails (4.0.10) with Hibernate5 (7.0.4) and a Postgres database (13). The Dynamic Update worked in the old grails version (3.3.1). After the Upgrade the dynamic update does not work agian.

There I have some objects with many fields and indexes on the table.
So an update on this table writes all fields every time.
I found the option to use dynamicUpdate true.
So I used

```
class InboundMessage extends Message {
    static mapping = {
        dynamicUpdate true
    }
 }
```

I used the same code in the Message object.
I logged the queries that are generated. But the update queries do not change. They still update all fields on every update.

Here is the example code:

```
InboundMessage msg = InboundMessage.get(447)
msg.userdefined1 = "test11"
println(msg.isDirty())
println(msg.listDirtyPropertyNames())
msg.save(flush:true)
```

Here are the generated queries (shortened):

```
Hibernate: select very long list of columns inner join message inboundmes0_1_ on inboundmes0_.id=inboundmes0_1_.id where inboundmes0_.id=?

Hibernate: update message set version=?, time_to_delete=?, client_address=?, .... where id=? and version=?
```

When I use dynamic for other domain classes, it works. There is only the changed field updated.  The output of listDirtyPropertyNames shows only the changed field. isDirty() is true.

What am I doing wrong? Is it because InboundMessage extends the Message Object? We use a message table and a seperate inbound message table.

Comment: Ideally, it should work but there is not enough information to tell what is wrong. Please note that for dynamic update to work both `get` and `update` must be in the same transaction. It would be great if you could create a sample application which isolates the problem.

Comment: I updated the description